# Entity Framework Code Generation without EDMX / MyGeneration

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-generation

Firstly, I guess it's been a while, I'm surprised to find www.mygenerationsoftware.com is no more. The actual code generator lives on at [Source Forge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mygeneration/files/), but where do you find template libraries for MyGeneration in the post www.mygenerationsoftware.com age?  It use to be here...

http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/templatelibrary/default.aspx

In particular I'm looking for Code First Entity Framework code generation templates.  I was looking to replace EDMX and T4 templates, with MyGeneration code generation.  Anyone have alternate strategies for code generating Entity Framework code from an existing database ?

What I'm wanting to achieve with my code generation, is modularisation.

In most enterprise applications, a single database will have a core set of tables, the rest of the tables can be broken up into several modules, each module having a dependency on the tables in the core of the product.

I'd like a code generation solution that doesn't just take a whole database and generates code for everything in one monolithic chunk of code, but allows you to generate code such that there is one cs file per entity and create a DbContext specific for each module.  i.e. each module would have it's entities + plus the core entities.

Comment: honestly never heard of MyGeneration, but I would imagine whatever it is meant to do, there are better ways to do now, since the last update to that code was in 2011....

Comment: Heard of Code Smith?  http://www.codesmithtools.com/  Mygeneration is a free alternative.  You've never heard of code generation?

Comment: yes, and I see they have a template, PLINQO for Entity Framework. http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks#plinqoef.  Just not familiar with any free / open source alternatives, and wouldn't trust a codebase from 2011, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: It's a code generator.... with code generation templates... that you can edit in 2014.  All CodeSmith and MyGeneration do is expose the database schema to templates that you can create and edit. From the template you can generate code off foreign key relationships, indexes, tables etc etc.  Create code in any language to do anything, based on a database schema.  It's very powerful.  I'd suggest putting on your indiana jones hat and discovering the power of these ancient treasures.  Entity Framework is just a dedicated code generator